# Japanese small-talk

Tags: politeness

As long as the conversation I'm having, follows the chapters in Genki I & II I'm sort of OK but as soon as I try to engage in some small-talk I'm lost!

Sentences like

ロバートさんは, どんなスポーツが好きですか

just sounds dorky!

Please help me with some nice sentences for starting a conversation with friends, business associates and general acquaintances that doesn't make me sound like well, reading out loud from Genki I.

Comment: Considering that you meet the reputation requirement, do join us in our [main chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/511/japanese-language-and-usage), or [in our other room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4291/). (You can practise small-talk-skills (albeit non-verbal))

Comment: didn't think of that, should be a great way to practice, thanks.

Comment: I learned from Genki too. Those dialogs with Mary and Takeshi are so ridiculous lol

Comment: Sorry, but this question is way too open-ended as it is for JLU. I would suggest following the comment suggestions above and joining the Chat to practice your conversational skills.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking for something that doesn't make much sense. You're looking for natural-sounding preset phrases that allow you to keep talking without saying anything.

How do you do small-talk in English? Usual topics for me are weather, local sports, travel, and food. Pretty much the same thing applies to Japanese. Sure, we could give you phrases that would start the conversation, but how would you deal with the reply in any of those cases if you're not sufficiently comfortable in the language to generate them yourself?

Comment: you are of course right, question is rather dumb! Although it can be really nice to have some prepared conversation-starters in your arsenal when those awkward silent moments arises.

Comment: Suddenly break the silence by saying how quiet it is =D. "静かですね"

Comment: Agreed, small talk is small talk no matter the language.